# Numpy dot issue during matrix by vector multiplication

Tags: numpy, matrix, python-3.7

**EDIT: Alright, so, I was indeed stupid. I recommend to close this question as it does not bring anything to the table. Basically, I suck at basic thinking and math at 2am...**

This is driving me insane. I'm trying to get the product of a matrix with a vector in python.

I have one 9x9 matrix a and one 1x9 vector b.

```
a = [[-0.03619046050233981, 0.01694804504223569, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.01694804504223569, -0.03619046050233981, 0.01694804504223569, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.01694804504223569, -0.03619046050233981, 0.01694804504223569, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.01694804504223569, -0.03619046050233981, 0.01694804504223569, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01694804504223569, -0.03619046050233981, 0.01694804504223569, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01694804504223569, -0.03619046050233981, 0.01694804504223569, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01694804504223569, -0.03619046050233981, 0.01694804504223569, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01694804504223569, -0.03619046050233981, 0.01694804504223569], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04756713402738598, -0.06941534088216819]]

a = np.array(a)

b = [2.774218316317263e-09, 1.9240011547847137e-09, 1.3342489213593189e-09, 9.251229045630879e-10, 6.412369741504171e-10, 4.441595895415701e-10, 3.07211064663576e-10, 2.1185176007909776e-10, -4.172326584582343e-11]

b = np.array(b)

print(np.dot(a,b))
>>> array([-6.77921802e-11,  0.00000000e+00,  6.46234854e-27,  0.00000000e+00,
    6.46234854e-27,  3.23117427e-27, -4.84676140e-27, -3.16751358e-12,
    1.29734158e-11])
```

What I'm expecting:

```
...
2nd value: 0.01694805 * 2.77421832e-09 -0.03619046 * 1.92400115e-09 + 0.01694805 * 1.33424892e-09
>>> 2.15478530e-17
...

array([-6.77921695e-11,  2.15478530e-17,  1.47710395e-17,  1.02173204e-17,
    7.13131671e-18,  4.91186255e-18,  3.40092760e-18,  2.36168005e-18,
   -7.44835521e-19])
```

Here is the kicker:

```
c = array([[-0.03619046,  0.01694805,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.01694805, -0.03619046,  0.01694805,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.01694805, -0.03619046,  0.01694805,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.01694805, -0.03619046,  0.01694805,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.01694805, -0.03619046,
     0.01694805,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.01694805,
    -0.03619046,  0.01694805,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.01694805, -0.03619046,  0.01694805,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.01694805, -0.03619046,  0.01694805],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.04756713, -0.06941534]])

np.dot(c,b)
>>> array([-6.77921692e-11,  2.13353146e-17,  1.47955319e-17,  1.02587195e-17,
    7.11069875e-18,  4.92530088e-18,  3.40667400e-18, -3.16751216e-12,
    1.29734149e-11])
```

As you can see, *c* is an approximation of *a* with less significant numbers. Using it gives me my expected results-ish. Am I hitting some numerical artifact ? Or am I making a huge and stupid mistake?

Note that a @ b and np.matmul(a,b) encounter the same issue.

I'm using Python 3.7.0 and Numpy 1.15.0

Comment: I'm not really sure what the problem is. You have calculated the 2nd number you should get, and it's much smaller than the factors used to obtain it, thus making the additional significant numbers more important.

Comment: In general you have these small numbers you might want to consider switching to a different precision. NumPy sets `float64` by default. You can change this using `.astype(dtype=np.float128)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you copy-pasted the numbers wrong.

```py
print(np.dot(a, b))
print(np.dot(a[1], b))
print(
    0.01694804504223569 * 2.774218316317263e-09
    + -0.03619046050233981 * 1.9240011547847137e-09
    + 0.01694804504223569 * 1.3342489213593189e-09
)
```

```
[-6.77921802e-11  0.00000000e+00  6.46234854e-27  0.00000000e+00
  6.46234854e-27  3.23117427e-27 -4.84676140e-27 -3.16751358e-12
  1.29734158e-11]
-6.462348535570529e-27
-6.462348535570529e-27
```

It's a bit weird that the `np.dot(a, b)[1]` does not exactly equal `np.dot(a[1], b)`, but with this magnitude it's not too surprising.

You could play with [accupy](https://github.com/nschloe/accupy)'s `kdot`/`fdot` (a project of mine) to see if those round-off defeating implementations do you any good.

Comment: You're 100% right, I apologize for wasting your time on a stupid math error on my part...